# Как поставить на сервер через ssh git репозиторий?

Tags: git, ssh

Нужно установить на сервер следующее

```
git clone https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq.git
sh -c "cd php-zmq && phpize && ./configure && make --silent && sudo make install"
echo "extension=zmq.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:s*||"`
```

пишу в ssh строку

```
git clone https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq.git
```

Пишет неизвестная команда, чего делать? Какой алгоритм действий. Я пока-что не могу понять.

Comment: `пишет неизвестная команда` покажите вывод консоли.

Comment: установить git... какой ещё тут может быть алгоритм действий... не?

Comment: @fat-zer, как его поставить на VDS?

Comment: Если вы обладаете правами root - то посмотрите мануал на свою систему (названия вы не сказали). Например, у меня в Centos это делается строкой `sudo yum install git`

Comment: @AK помогло! Теперь требует -bash-4.2$ sh -c "cd php-zmq && phpize && ./configure && make --silent && sudo make install"
Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
The php-devel package is required for use of this command.

Comment: Это уже не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу установки git. Не хочу обсуждать слишком разные вопросы в одном. Создайте новый, укажите что у вас за сервер, укажите, что вы пытаете делать (похоже собираете какой-то доп. модуль для веб-сервера), либо давайте сформулируем вопрос не только о гит, но и всех остальных модулях, которые есть у вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы обладаете правами root - то посмотрите мануал на свою систему (названия вы не сказали в вопросе).

Например, у меня в Centos это делается строкой

```
sudo yum install git
```

Если вы пишете, что у вас VDS (virtual dedicated server), то там дают порулить системой на уровне root.

PS Ну и если на сервере нет php-zmq - то и его поставьте через yum, команда точно такая же - либо `sudo yum install php-zmq`, либо `sudo yum install php56w-zmq` или `sudo yum install php70-zmq` - точное значение можно узнать через yum provides, yum search и прочие команды, см. [шпаргалку по yum](https://habrahabr.ru/post/301292/).

Answer (score 1):

Если поставить гит не возможно, то есть вагон обходных маневров. git clone можно заменить на

- если есть wget

  wget https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq/archive/master.zip
  tar xvf master.zip
- если есть curl

  сurl -o master.zip https://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq/archive/master.zip
  tar xvf master.zip

если на сервере нет ни curl, wget и tar, но есть ssh доступ, то качаем репозиторий локально, а потом заливаем через ssh - `scp -r <локальная папка> <ssh-сервер>:~/` и папка будет в домашнем каталоге на сервере (нужна ли там папка .git - не знаю, но мало чего).

P.S. Всегда можно использовать любой доступный sftp клиент или на web морде в админке найти доступ о ftp (он  бывает просто выключен по умолчанию) или веб-файл-навигатор.